# What are unused variables set to?

Tags: javascript

Particularly for `localStorage.foo`

For Safari it is set to:

```
undefined
```

For Firefox it is set to:

```
null
```

Does anyone know the values for Chrome and IE?

Why is it different?  Just random choices by browser programmers?

Comment: As long as they are falsy values, does it matter?

Comment: @TheZ: What if I wanted to store `false` as the value?

Comment: @Rocket Just check against `=== false` if you really care. Javascript usually has that caveat anyways, nothing new here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's always `undefined`.  Perhaps your observation method is what led you to believe the values are different in different browsers.

Oh, I'll qualify that statement for old versions of IE, which might do some other thing for all I know. I bet they use `undefined` also.

Ah - Mr. Protagonist has an interesting point. On any *normal* object, a non-existent property will be `null`.  However, Firefox does indeed seem to report `null` as the value of a non-existent property specifically of `localStorage`.  Hmm... My vote would be that that's a bug, but I'll check the w3c spec (or proto-spec or whatever it is).

The "value" `undefined` isn't really a value; it's more like the Buddhist *mu* — it's kinda like saying, "what you asked for doesn't make sense".  The value `null` in JavaScript is treated differently than `undefined`.  Thus:

```
var a = {};
var b = a.banana;
```

The variable "b" will be `undefined`. It's weird, but it lets you tell the difference between a property being present but `null` and a property being missing. (Of course, the `in` operator lets you figure that out too.)

Comment: Firebug in Firefox 13 says `localStorage.foo` is `null`.

Comment: I just double checked...it is null

Comment: Yes I've just seen that too.  I personally think that's a bug.

Comment: I'll file it...how do you file it?

Comment: But in general....why is there more then one falsy value...they all mean the same thing....right?

Comment: There's a Bugzilla instance; something like buzilla.mozilla.org.  You might want to see if there's mention made in any sort of w3c spec you can find.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist I'll add to my answer